# how do I releaseExport part using managed extensibility framework

Tags: mef

I understand that **CompositionContainer.ReleaseExport()** works as follows:

1. it exexutes the Dispose method of the part;
2. it removes the part from the CompositionContainer.

I've attached a short program. When the program runs, I expect to see

1. text "this is Foo.Dispose" in the console window, and
2. in the debugger, composablePartCatalog.Parts count should be zero.

It ain't so. Can anybody shed light on this?

In response to Daniel Plaisted's reply, I've simplified the sample program. I still don't see text "this is Foo.Dispose" in the console window.

```
namespace MefCa06
{
  using System;
  using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
  using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
  using System.Reflection;

  [
      ExportAttribute
    , PartCreationPolicyAttribute(CreationPolicy.NonShared)
  ]
  public class Foo : IDisposable
  {
    public void ShowMessage()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("this is Foo.ShowMessage");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("this is Foo.Dispose");
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    [ImportAttribute]
    public Foo FooProperty { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Program program = new Program();

      CompositionContainer compositionContainer =
        new CompositionContainer(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
      compositionContainer.ComposeParts(program);

      program.FooProperty.ShowMessage();

      Lazy<Foo> foo = compositionContainer.GetExport<Foo>();
      compositionContainer.ReleaseExport(foo);

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should see "this is Foo.Dispose" in the console.

The catalog should still have the part in it.  Catalogs contain part definitions, containers contain parts.  The part/instance of Foo will be disposed and removed from the container, but the definition will still be in the catalog.  Since the definition is still in the catalog, you could create another one with another call to GetExport.

Comment: (1) I've updated my program, simplifying it. I don't see "this is Foo.Dispose." Can you explain why? (2) You distinguish between part definitions and parts. Does it imply that in your last sentence, you mean to say: Since the definition is still in the catalog, you could create another PART with another call to GetExport?

Comment: @user669226 (1) The Foo is never created because you never access the Value property of the lazy.  So there's nothing to dispose.  (2) Yes, you could create another PART.